# Не работает код (простейшая задача)

Tags: c++, функции

Нужно составить код с функцией по данному условию: На товар дважды была сделана скидка – на p1, а затем на p2 процентов. Первоначальная стоимость товара составляла S рублей. Используя функцию вычисления стоимости товара с учетом скидки на P процентов, найти стоимость товара после двойной скидки.
По формуле, которая указанна в коде. При вводе значений он выдает в любом случае 0. Помогите найти ошибку и объясните ее, пожалуйста.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Посмотрев ваши комментарии я решил свою проблему, она работает и это меня устраивает, спасибо вам =З
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Неужели сделать скриншот и вставить его проще, чем просто скопировать код (как того требуют правила, которые вы не потрудились прочесть)?

Comment: ну вот почему вы приводите код изображением? Код - это текстовая инфа, ее же проще скопировать. К тому же если кто-то бы хотел проверить ваш код и скомпилировать его то что он должен сделать? Вручную переписать код?

Comment: По теме: нужно срочно брать учебник и читать про типы данных. В данном случае о int, float/double.

Comment: Извините ребята, я первый раз тут, в следующий раз буду прикреплять текстом.

Comment: @Wiltshire вопросы можно редактировать

Comment: @Wiltshire Вставьте код не картинкой, а кодом.  Почитайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  ознакомьтесь со справкой.

Comment: По условию задачи вам нужна функция `float discount(float);`

Answer (score 1):

у вас же в задаче указана двойная скидка - `p1` и `p2`

так и применяйте скидку на `p1`, а затем на `p2`

```
C = (1 - p1) * (1 - p2) * S
```

только желательно потом до копеек округлить хотя бы

касательно вашей функции:

1. зачем вы переменные все сделали глобальными то? `P, S` хорошо делаются локальными, а `C` функция возвращает через `return`
2. и когда считаются скидки (выполняется деление) не надо использовать тип `int`, надо использовать тип с плавающей запятой (например, `float`), потому что

   ```
    (100 - P) / P
   ```

при `P > 50` будет равно строго 0, а при  `P < 50` тоже всякой фигне

Comment: Нет, 0 в результате по другой причине.

Comment: @Эникейщик, ноль из за int, я про то, что задача не соответствует даже условию

Comment: `P > 50`.. 99/100 == 0